# how can I used noconflict for bootstrap js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am build JavaScript application for third party. I used bootstrap-js 3 for application and third party using bootstrap-js 2. I thing some bootstrap-js call get conflict (not working). any suggestion??

Comment: no, they cannot be used together without modification because the declarative html markup that feeds the script overlaps between versions, so they would fight over who toggles a data-toggle for example... the closest simple thing you can do is making custom builds of each, avoiding conflicts by not overlapping functionality; for example, use bs2 for modals and bs3 for drop-downs...